# How can I upload photos from an external HD to Google+?

Tags: photos, mount, instant-upload, google-plus-photos

I have 40K photos on my desktop that I'd like to archive/upload on Google+ Photos or flickr. The desktop uploaders don't make this easy, i.e. 999 photo limit to Picasa Album uploads or 200 photo limit in Flickr WebUploader.

Is there any way to "mount" the HD as an external/network drive to an Android device, "sym link" the camera roll, and let the mobile app do it's 'autobackup' thing?

Comment: It depends on whether the device you're using supports USB host mode. To tell you whether that will work, we need to know what Android device you're using.

Comment: Why don't you just add them to Google Drive from your desktop? https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3259546?p=photos_drive&hl=en&authuser=0&rd=1

Comment: Will I get unlimited 2048px photos from uploading from Drive this way? Its 80GB in full res.

Comment: In this case, its a galaxy nexus.